# Find $f(z)$ given that $\Im f$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any way to find $~f(z)$ if one knows that $\Im~ f(z)$ is analytic/meromorphic in some region.

Ex. Suppose we have

$$ \Im ~f(x) = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ln{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}} $$
is there a way to find the whole of $~f(z)$?

Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $f(z)$ is analytic in the upper half-plane and vanishes faster than $1/|z|$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$, then you can get the real part from the imaginary part of $f$, and vice-versa, from the [Kramers-Kroenig relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations):

$$\Re{f(z)} = \frac{1}{\pi} PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz' \: \frac{\Im{f(z')}}{z'-z}$$

$$\Im{f(z)} = -\frac{1}{\pi} PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz' \: \frac{\Re{f(z')}}{z'-z}$$

where $PV$ denotes the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral.

Comment: @Jebus: you're welcome.  If an answer is useful to you, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: The Wiki article states that $f$ must be real, so that in my special case $x$ must be real?

Comment: Where do you see that?  $f$ is a complex function, analytic in the upper half-plane.  In the article, they use $\chi$ for your $f$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. I can clearify: So if we consider my situation we have: $f = Re f + i Im f$ but my Im f is not real if x is complex so that KK-relations doesn't apply for complex x, right?

Comment: Well, remember that the integration takes place over the real line, so you are OK.

Comment: Yeah that's what I also thought...hmmm interesting...thanks for the conversation brother.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is, in a sense, the interaction between the imaginary part and real part of a function that determines holomorphicness. Assuming we're on some simply connected domain there exists precisely one function $R(z)$ on the domain such that

$$R(z)+\text{Im}(f(z)$$

is holomorphic. So, unless your function $f$ has $\text{Re}(f)=R$, then you're out of luck.